# Unix: How to do mkdir, cp, without mkdir?

Tags: linux, unix

So script2 is:

```
find /some_directory -type f -not -iname "*.pdf" -exec bash -c './script "{}"' \; -print > temp_file
while read line
do
   mkdir -p result"$(dirname "$line")"
   cp "$line" ~/result"$(dirname "$line")"/$(basename "$line" .txt).pdf
done < temp_file
rm temp_file
```

the ./script is `file "$1"|grep -q PDF`

These two combined should find .txt files that are actually PDF files and then copy them to some result directory and rename them to .pdf file. But the files should be in: `result/their/original/directories/file.pdf`. (if the original was `some_directory/their/original/directories/file.txt`, also some directories have space in them, thus a lot of `".."`)

It is done, it works, but the question is: how to do it without mkdir?

I've tried many things but none seem to work and every post i read it says that it can be done just by using mkdir (but because my professor demands it to be done without mkdir, I'm quite sure it can be done. I don't HAVE to do it, but I'd like to know how it can be done).

Maybe it can be done in find with piping? (some argument that would print directories first and they would be copied one by one and then files?) I've wasted a lot of time on this and it would be a shame to quit it without correct answear.

Comment: Use the `-a` flag with the cp command.

Comment: @kometen you mean just add -a to cp? If so it doesn't work and man says nothing about it, so I'm not sure what it's supposed to do or how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy a file while creating the leading target directories with [`install`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/install.1.html):

```
install -D src/file dest/src/file
```

Comment: Just note that this will set the default permissions to rwxr-xr-x.

Comment: This isn't a good approach. It changes the permissions of the file.

Comment: @GrabbenD This is the default whenever you copy a file.

Comment: @ceving FILE's permission are: `-rw-r--r--`. After using `install -D src/FILE dst/FILE` this gets transformed into `-rwxr-xr-x`. If you instead use e.g. `cp` or `rsync -a` you'll retain the original permissions.

Comment: @GrabbenD `cp` No, `cp -a` Yes

Comment: Didn't need `cp -a` in neither Arch Linux nor Gentoo for the correct permissions to be retained